# How to speed up writing in a database?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a function which search for json files in a directory, parse the file and write data in the database. My problem is writing in database, because it take around 30 minutes. Any idea how can I speed up writting in a database? I have few quite big files to parse, but parsing the file is not a problem it take around 3 minutes. Currently I am using sqlite but in the future I will change it to PostgreSQL.

Here is my function:

```
def create_database():
    with transaction.atomic():
        directory = os.fsencode('data/web_files/unzip')
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)

            with open('data/web_files/unzip/{}'.format(filename.strip()), encoding="utf8") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                cve_items = data['CVE_Items']
                for i in range(len(cve_items)):
                    database_object = DataNist()

                    try:
                        impact = cve_items[i]['impact']['baseMetricV2']
                        database_object.severity = impact['severity']
                        database_object.exp_score = impact['exploitabilityScore']
                        database_object.impact_score = impact['impactScore']
                        database_object.cvss_score = impact['cvssV2']['baseScore']

                    except KeyError:
                        database_object.severity = ''
                        database_object.exp_score = ''
                        database_object.impact_score = ''
                        database_object.cvss_score = ''

                    for vendor_data in cve_items[i]['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data']:
                            database_object.vendor_name = vendor_data['vendor_name']

                            for description_data in cve_items[i]['cve']['description']['description_data']:
                                database_object.description = description_data['value']

                            for product_data in vendor_data['product']['product_data']:
                                database_object.product_name = product_data['product_name']
                                database_object.save()

                                for version_data in product_data['version']['version_data']:
                                    if version_data['version_value'] != '-':
                                    database_object.versions_set.create(version=version_data['version_value'])
```

My models.py:

```
class DataNist(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    severity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    exp_score = models.IntegerField()
    impact_score = models.IntegerField()
    cvss_score = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor_name + "-" + self.product_name


class Versions(models.Model):
    data = models.ForeignKey(DataNist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.version
```

I will appreciate if you can give me any advice how can I improve my code.

Comment: Your code seems to be overwriting `.vendor_name`, `.description` and  `.product_name` in the same `database_object`. Is that what you're actually looking for?

Comment: @AKX I get the result that I want, but it take to much to get it. I am junior python programer and I am looking for any useful advice how to optimize and speed up my code.

Comment: I'm just saying you might have a bug in there since you're overwriting those values within a loop.

Comment: In addition, if there are multiple `product_data` entries, you're re-re-re-saving the same object with a different `product_name`, wasting time.

Comment: Thirdly, if any of the four keys in that `try: except KeyError:` block is missing, _all_ of the values in the database object get cleared. That doesn't sound like the correct behavior.

Comment: @AKX There are multiple product_data, what do you recommend to do?

Comment: If you want a `database_object` for each of them, create them within that loop...

Comment: @AKX Which one?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload one of those JSON files, or a part thereof?

Comment: @AKX you can download ziped json file form https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, given the structure of the data, something like this might work for you.

This is standalone code aside from that `.objects.bulk_create()` call; as commented in the code, the two classes defined would actually be models within your Django app.
(By the way, you probably want to save the CVE ID as an unique field too.)

Your original code had the misassumption that every "leaf entry" in the affected version data would have the same vendor, which may not be true.  That's why the model structure here has a separate product-version model that has vendor, product and version fields. (If you wanted to optimize things a little, you might deduplicate the `AffectedProductVersion`s even across `DataNist`s (which, as an aside, is not a perfect name for a model)).

And of course, as you had already done in your original code, the importing should be run within a transaction (`transaction.atomic()`).

Hope this helps.

```py
import json
import os
import types


class DataNist(types.SimpleNamespace):  # this would actually be a model
    severity = ""
    exp_score = ""
    impact_score = ""
    cvss_score = ""

    def save(self):
        pass


class AffectedProductVersion(types.SimpleNamespace):  # this too
    # (foreign key to DataNist here)
    vendor_name = ""
    product_name = ""
    version_value = ""


def import_item(item):
    database_object = DataNist()
    try:
        impact = item["impact"]["baseMetricV2"]
    except KeyError:  # no impact object available
        pass
    else:
        database_object.severity = impact.get("severity", "")
        database_object.exp_score = impact.get("exploitabilityScore", "")
        database_object.impact_score = impact.get("impactScore", "")
        if "cvssV2" in impact:
            database_object.cvss_score = impact["cvssV2"]["baseScore"]

    for description_data in item["cve"]["description"]["description_data"]:
        database_object.description = description_data["value"]
        break  # only grab the first description

    database_object.save()  # save the base object

    affected_versions = []
    for vendor_data in item["cve"]["affects"]["vendor"]["vendor_data"]:
        for product_data in vendor_data["product"]["product_data"]:
            for version_data in product_data["version"]["version_data"]:
                affected_versions.append(
                    AffectedProductVersion(
                        data_nist=database_object,
                        vendor_name=vendor_data["vendor_name"],
                        product_name=product_data["product_name"],
                        version_name=version_data["version_value"],
                    )
                )

    AffectedProductVersion.objects.bulk_create(
        affected_versions
    )  # save all the version information

    return database_object  # in case the caller needs it


with open("nvdcve-1.0-2019.json") as infp:
    data = json.load(infp)
    for item in data["CVE_Items"]:
        import_item(item)
```

Comment: Now I have a problem how to implement it to my project. I do not understand how your models work and where to place it. Should I remove existing models and replace them with yours?

Comment: I add my models.py to my question.

Comment: There's nothing special to my "models" (as they aren't really models in the answer, as it was designed to be mostly standalone-runnable code). You should at least adapt your `Versions` class (btw, class names should be singular) to have the three fields of my version; otherwise that `DataNist` model looks good. `.objects.bulk_create()` accepts a list of unsaved model objects it will create, see the documentation.

Comment: I am trying to asign database_object to the variable in AffectedProductVersion, but I do not know how. If I try to do it like you do I get error `table db_affectedproductversion has no column named data_nist_id`. I tried some other things without success.

Comment: Your model has `data = models.ForeignKey(DataNist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, not `data_nist = ...`, so use `data=database_object` instead.